# How to use methods of 'DateTime' object from parameters that is declared type as 'object'

Tags: c#

I want to use `object` type as a parameter in order to get value from various type (`int,string,datetime`,etc) and return the string representation of the object.

But I have a problem with `DateTime`. I know that `object` is a parent class of `DateTime` so there won't have any method of it child class.

So is there any way to copy some value from `object` and instantiate a new `DateTime` object
or there is any other method.

```
    public static string getStringOfValue(object value)
    {
        // all of this List is used for type checking //////////////
        List<object> _number_type_list = new List<object>()
        {
            typeof(byte), typeof(sbyte), typeof(int), typeof(long),
            typeof(short), typeof(ushort), typeof(uint), typeof(ulong),
            typeof(float), typeof(float), typeof(decimal)
        };
        List<object> _string_type_list = new List<object>()
        {
            typeof(char),typeof(string)
        };
        List<object> _boolean_type_list = new List<object>()
        {
            typeof(bool)
        };
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // used for format string of DateTime
        string SQL_DATETIME_FORMAT = "YYYYMMdd hhmmss.fff";


        var value_type = value.GetType();
        var value_string = "";

        if (_number_type_list.Contains(value_type) || _boolean_type_list.Contains(value_type))
        {
            value_string = value.ToString();
        }

        else if (_string_type_list.Contains(value_type))
        {
            value_string = "'" + value + "'";
        }

        else if (value.GetType() == typeof(System.DateTime))
        {
            //// how can I use format string method of DateTime ////
            value_string = value.ToString();
            // value_string = value.ToString(SQL_DATETIME_FORMAT);
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }

        return value_string;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I use format string method of `DateTime`

Cast your `value` to `DateTime` before making the call:

```
value_string = ((DateTime)value).ToString(SQL_DATETIME_FORMAT);
```